# meaning of "technological pitch"

Tags: meaning, translation

What is the meaning of word "pitch" in this sentence?

Job hunters are increasingly open to technological pitches, he noted.
http://nrn.com/hr-training/tech-tools-help-restaurants-recruit-retain-workers?page=1

I found a lot of meanings in the dictionary, but they all do not seem appropriate.

Comment: You must have missed ***pitch*** - [*a ​speech or ​act that ​attempts to ​persuade someone to ​buy or **do** something*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pitch) (such as take a job offer made using technological tools).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[dictionary.reference.com's](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pitch?s=t) definition 41a is the relevant for your quoted usage as a noun:

> 41 a. *Informal.* a high-pressure sales talk

although I personally disagree that it is necessarily "high pressure". The relevant definitions for this usage as a verb are useful to see too (note than none of these mention "high pressure"):

> 10 *Informal.* to attempt to sell or win approval for; promote; advertise
>
> 11 *Informal.* to approach or court (as a person, company, or the public) in hope of a sale, approval, or interest; make an appeal to.
>
> 24 *Informal.* to attempt to sell or win approval for something or someone by advertising, promotion, etc.

---

By the way, if you can't find the correct definitions from my link, there are little expandable "down arrows" to show more results. I don't know whether this may have been why you weren't able to find it in your own research.